# Looking for an online IDE

Tags: c#, java, ide, editor

I have been looking for a fairly decent online IDE that does well with both c# and java, I have tried Cloud9IDE, CodeRun, and Amy Editor.  I really had liked CodeRun until i found that it was impossible for me to add another file into the same project, unless i was just doing it wrong which is possible.  Amy Editor was very promising also until i couldn't figure out how to create a new project or compile the sample code i had written.  If anyone knows how to use these editors or of any other good online IDE environments then I'm game to learn.

Comment: I'll always choose an offline IDE like Eclipse for practicing/learning.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use one of the many free offline IDEs?

Comment: The only reason is that I don't have my computer with me at work and don't have the rights to install any software so i was thinking a cloud based  or online ide would be my best solution

Comment: How do you mean it was "impossible to add another file into the same project"? Is this something different to right-clicking and selecting Add?

Comment: Don't you have any IDE at work???

Comment: @Graham Clark, when ever i would do that it would just open a new file and not add it to the solution i was working on

Comment: @Harry Joy, I'm currently in college and work in the library as a student employee and they feel that we IT guys here at the desk have no clue what we are doing lol

Comment: [http://compilr.com/](http://compilr.com/), but I've never tried it myself.

Comment: @ninja, I had seen that one but wasn't what i was looking for

Comment: @Bill, I just tried going into CodeRun, created a new ASP.NET application, right-clicked on the "ASPNetApplication" project (i.e. the 2nd item down in the tree-view on the right), selected Add, New Item, Class, and it appeared in the project. Seems to work fine!

Comment: @Graham Clark, I guess just right-clicking the solution doesn't do that. Now I feel really dumb :(

Comment: Coderun appears to be dead, but I just tried https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and it looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not run your IDE somewhere on a machine and connect to it remotely? You can even install your own Virtual Desktop on Amazon EC2 for example, so you don't have to run the machine yourself. For an idea on how to do this see http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2010/11/show-off-ubuntu-desktop-on-cloud/ for example.

Comment: but why? if you want to practice solving interview problems, share your solutions, and have access from it from anywhere on any platform, tools like Coderpad.io are much more convenient and easy to use.  They even support a test framework for unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Compilr](http://compilr.com/)?

I think it's only been up and running for a few months but it's a pretty good website, not sure if it meets your functionality needs though.

Comment: looks like it's dead.